# How to add shadow in dropdown spinner in Android

Tags: android

I am using a Spinner drop down in my Form. But when I drop down my spinner, the color of it is matching to background color. How can I add shadow to my dropdown spinner in Android

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I got the answer, this worked for me

```
android:popupBackground="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `elevation` to it (API 21+). Here is how to do it in XML:

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

Comment: What about adding the following: `android:clipToPadding="false"` since your shadow might be cut by the view bounds

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:popupElevation="10dp"`

Tested using AppCompatSpinner

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

Hope this helps.